# Waiting for the contentscript to finish before looping next item in background script in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, async-await, content-script

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension, but got a bit of a headache due to the whole asynchronous programming and communicating.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is the following:

1. Loop over an array in the background script
2. Send a message to the content script that it has to execute a function. Tell the background script when it's done with the result
   data.
3. Now the background script should be waiting for the result to be received before going to the next item in the array.
4. When it has received the data, it should move on to the next item in the array

This is the backgroundscript part which sends messages to the contentscript with single search queries.

```
async function searchGoogle(url) {
  let terms = ["food", "nature", "computers", "trees", "clothing"];
  console.log(terms);

  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, async function (tabs) {

    terms.forEach(function (term) {
      console.log("Sending term..");
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { msg: "SEARCH_SINGLE_TERM", term: term }, function (response) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(response);
        }, 5000);

        console.log(response);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

This is the contentscript which listens for the background queries one by one, and then searches it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch (message.msg) {
      case "SEARCH_SINGLE_TERM":
        firstUrl = searchSingleTerm(message.term);
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
          console.log("starting wait");
          setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
        }).then(() => {
          console.log("done waiting");
          sendResponse(firstUrl)
        });
    }
    return true; // for sendResponse so it doesn't close the listener
  });
});


function searchSingleTerm(term) {
  document.querySelector('.gLFyf.gsfi').value = term

  console.log("-- Executing click search button--");
  document.querySelector('.Tg7LZd').click();

  let firstUrl = document.querySelector('.yuRUbf a').href

  return firstUrl
}
```

Right now it still executes everything at the same time (it sends 5 messages to content script which all run at the same time instead of serially). How can I convert it from parallel to serial?

The full POC is on github, which can be found here: https://github.com/YungFrikandelbroodje/SearchPOC

This is just to demonstrate the issue. I know an extension like this wouldn't really have any use, but it shows the exact problem ;)

In the readme, I wrote some more information to make it as clear as possible!

Thanks!

Comment: Questions are expected to be self contained.  Questions that link to resources, especially those that are bound to be modified over time, are highly likely to become unuseful to future readers.  The question should be updated to include enough information to express the issue without requiring the access to off site resources.

Comment: @Taplar Ah okay, I think thats difficult to do since it's too much code to just paste in the question. How would you suggest to improve the question? I can't really put it on a codepen aswell since you need to have it in your browser.

Comment: It's fine to link to stuff.  That just doesn't need to be the only way to get to the logic.  Since your question appears to be around the logic that sends and receives messages, at a minimum citing and showing some reduced snippets related to those parts of the code would be good.  Also, if you can, rather than making a codepen or a jsfiddle, S.O. offers an onsite snippet runner with the use of the `<>` button in the editor or hitting Ctrl+M.  But if the code is very large, that can become a code dump.  So I admit it is a balancing act in giving too much and too little.

Comment: Alright thanks, I will try to update my question to make it better!

Comment: Don't use `terms.forEach`. Instead use a standard `for` with `await` inside, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65518329).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks a lot! It finally worked after so long of trying :)
Now my next question would be: how would you wait for a specific element to be visible on page instead of when the page has fully loaded?